# What are the matching algorithms for calendars?

Tags: algorithm, calendar, matching

I am working on an api which generates a notification when you and someone in your circle are in same geolocation. What is the best matching algorithm for this problem.

Comment: this is to broad IMHO: Is distance your only criteria? or are there other parameters? are there a limit to the number of people you can match with?

Comment: DIstance and the people who are in your circle, like your friends or colleagues

Comment: What do you mean by calenders? It seems like you want to match the geo-location (find 2 people in close distance), no?